# Contradiction of gradient between direction of steepest increase and local minimum

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, gradient-descent

I can understand the proof that at a local minimum, the gradient of that function must be zero. But I can't understand it together with the fact that gradient points the steepest increase, since if it is at local minimum, then moving at any direction will give the function some increment. So what does gradient being zero at this point means? If any direction increases this function, then why don't we just choose the direction with the greatest increment but choose zero which means not to move at all?

Comment: If you are not at a local minimum, then the direction of steepest descent is the most likely direction towards the local minimum. If you are at a local minimum, then the gradient in each direction is 0 and you don't need to go anywhere.

Comment: Imagine zooming in on the minimum with a magnifying glass. If you zoom in enough, at the minimum point the function will be indistinguishable from flat.

Comment: Having non-zero gradient is not compatible with "in any direction function is increasing". Just imagine that function is increasing in direction $\mathbf{v}$; but then it means that it's decreasing in direction $-\mathbf{v}$. The only choice then is to have zero gradient. (Of course this reasoning requires a directional derivative but I think you are aware of it)

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the function is differentiable at a point of local minimum any partial derivative is equal to zero (as in the case of the function of one variable) thus the gradient is zero